# Best Database for range queries on a single column

Tags: database-recommendation

here's my usecase: I have these fields: `id(int)`, `frequency(int)`, `created(timestamp)`.

I need a database that can optimize range queries on `created` field. Specifically for queries like: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE created >= val1 AND created <= val2`

This db needs to handle millions of queries and also scale properly.

I've looked at Cassandra and understood that it doesn't work well for range splice queries like this since it needs to query all partitions. I suppose I could simply create an index on the `created` column and query it in a SQL type db but the reason I'm not looking at SQL db is that it won't be able to scale well (like there's no auto-sharding available in SQL dbs for example).

Please let me know of any db suggestions for this usecase. Thank you!

Comment: How many rows do you expect in the table? And how many rows are typically returned by such a query. Unless you have hundreds of billions of rows, a relational database can absolutely handle such a query quite efficiently.

Comment: Bear in mind that a B+ tree has `O(log2(n))` search complexity, so a well indexed table with 1bn rows only requires 30 lookups, and even 1tn rows only requires 40. It also allows forward and and backwards scanning from any row, so it's pretty efficient

Comment: @Charlieface Upvote for pointing out the Big-O of B-Trees. Just curious, how do you come up with 30 lookups for 1 billion rows? My math is pretty dusty with Big-O equations. I was thinking just doing log2(n) where n = number of rows, but log2(1 billion) = 9 so I think I'm doing something wrong lol.

Comment: @Chaflieface I think I figured out my mistake. I was doing log(n) (by default base 10), when I need to explicitly be doing log2(n) (base 2). That makes sense. 

Comment: @J.D. Indeed, that is the exact calculation. Remember that is only the average, pathological cases can vary widely. Long and short of it, most cases of people complaining about relational database performance (joins etc) is a case of bad indexing or poor design

Answer (score 1):

I'll raise a_horse_with_no_name's ante, and tell you I've personally worked with multi-terabyte databases in Microsoft SQL Server that had single tables in the hundreds of billions of rows without any form of **Sharding** or **Partitioning** setup, and ran just fine. I've even discussed the topic with Microsoft representatives who've claimed the system can handle tables into the trillions of rows.

Specifically I've worked with range queries (including on fields like a `CreatedDate`) on tables in the tens of billions of rows, and they were efficient and performed **index seeks** when appropriate (based on the **cardinality** of my predicates). The hardware behind the servers these databases ran on were as modest as an average laptop, in some cases.

As far as any modern database system goes (relational or not), you shouldn't choose one based solely on the **amount of data** you plan to support. Rather you should choose one based on the **type of data** (inclusive of it being structured, semi-structured, unstructured, or highly variable), and your **use-cases** for that data such as the type of querying you plan to do.

With such a skinny and structured table of only three columns with *lightweight* data types, I see no reason why any modern relational database management system couldn't handle your requirements. Proper indexing and architecting will go the longest of ways towards your performance and scalability, as opposed to which database system you actually choose.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I agree with what you said about what factors to consider while choosing a db. I've simplified my use-case here. Let's say that my schemas do change periodically. So I'm still curious to know which no-sql dbs would be efficient for queries such as ```SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE created >= val1 AND created <= val2```. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: @MaC How frequent is periodically, and how much of a change? E.g. when I worked with the large tables I mentioned in my answer above, I was making schema changes almost daily. I do not consider that highly variable. To clarify, highly variable was some of our other data we ingested from multiple external sources, and the schema was completely different from one source to another, so if our use cases were to just store the data as is and ship it off somewhere else, then a **NoSQL** solution would've made sense, but because we wanted to process that data we used **ETL** and kept it stored in...

Comment: ...our Microsoft SQL Server database. So even highly variable schemas can be easily managed in a relational database system. In any case, if you're still hard struck on using a **NoSQL** solution, as I mentioned in my answer, **any** modern **NoSQL** database should be equally performant when comparing based on amount of data. My recommendation there would be to focus on one that has a strong user base and documentation, that's been around long enough and has all the necessary features, e.g. **MongoDB**, **Redis**, maybe **DynamoDB** if you want a cloud solution.